# How do I find out what originally caused an exception, if it gets thrown from Microsoft's code?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, datagridview, dockpanel

I have two controls containing `DataGridView`s on different panes in a `DockPanel`.  If one is in edit mode and I switch pane, I get a `NullReferenceException` thrown from within the `DataGridView`'s `EndEdit()` method.  The stack trace doesn't go any deeper than that and the exception doesn't contain any more information.

I've looked at that method in the reflector, and I can't see anything obviously null.  I suspect that the problem is actually in my code, but the exception is being rethrown from within Microsoft's code and that's resetting the stack trace.   How do I find out what originally caused the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you suspect a bug in the MS code, you could download the debugging symbols from the symbol server, load them and trace it through at debug? [Like so](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

Note that the symbols are subject to one of the various licences. This may impact you if (for example) you work on "mono" contributions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the InnerException property?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions to set up MS [symbol server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx) and [source server](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. Set the debugger to break on NullReferenceException being thrown. Then either you will get full source code for debugging, or at least a complete stack trace.

<sup>1</sup> Note, the QFE listed is included in SP1.